# Benefit cards combination for Berlin

Tags: transportation, berlin, museums

I am going to travel to Germany in a few days (for a total of 5 days, Monday morning to Friday morning actually) and I am striving in various sites to conclude on the best combination out of:

Berlin Pass, Welcome Card, Museum Pass, Weekly transportation ticket.

- Welcome card offers benefits but I don't see discounts or free passes on the major museums I want to go. I doubt I will visit the smaller ones, so is it worth just because it offers free transportation? Maybe worth because of the restaurants' discounts?
- Berlin Pass looks great, but are the ~100 euros worth it?
- Museum Pass is surely a great deal. Only 24 euros where a major museum might cost 10 euros on it's own. Are the additional 37 euros a good bargain for transportation (check next as well)? This is my main focus for now.
- My hotel is near Alexanderplatz. Will I really need to spend a lot of money in transportation if I want to explore the city? I enjoy walking, unless the weather is really bad (or the place weird and creepy :) ).

I am not sure which combination is more beneficial from a budget along with benefits perspective. Can people that have been there or live in Berlin shed some light? My budget is 50-60 euros and ideally I'm looking for just one pass.

Comment: If you don't want to use public transit, you can rent a bike and cycle everywhere.  But you will definitely want either a BVG pass or bike.  Like the others say, the rest of the question is more or less not answerable, since the passes you mention cover a very narrow slice of things to do in Berlin.

Comment: We really can't tell you whether €100 is “worth it”, in general. Personally, I much prefer a pass for public transports and I rarely find the rest worthwhile. Once you sunk tens of euros in a pass, you also feel a bit compelled to maximise the return by doing things that are included and I much prefer to stay flexible, with no pressure. But that's just me and whether you can save money depends on what you want to do exactly, you will have to research this and run the numbers yourself. OTOH, the walkability/public transport bit is a good question in itself, maybe concentrate on that first?

Comment: @Relaxed: The short answer to this question is: "yes, you will want an AB transit pass".  Alex isn't particularly close to anything, even if you plan to just stay in Mitte and Friedrichshain.

Comment: @Louis That's not exactly my opinion (Alex-Museuminsel is completely walkable) but that's completely irrelevant to my comment. I would provide my own answer once the question is revised.

Comment: Yeah bdarenburg gate and museum island are really walkable for my standards. Not sure about other places. I am mostly afraid of the weather to be honest. Regarding museum card, I think it will pay off if I go to at least two big museums. If I buy it online, will the voucher that they will send me work? Can I buy it from the airport(Tegel) or somewhere locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [7-day-ticket](https://shop.bvg.de/index.php/product/462/show/0/0/0/0/buy) is 30 to 37 Euro, depending on the area. Going for zone ABC rather than AB would pay for itself if you travel into C once or twice.

Depending on the exact timeline, four day tickets plus a single ticket on Friday might be cheaper, but the savings are marginal.

This includes no museum admittances, but I don't know what you want to visit and how often. Last time I checked, not all Museums were included.

Comment: *Going for zone ABC rather than AB would pay for itself if you travel into C once or twice.* An *Anschlussfahrschein* is 1.60E, so you need to make at least four single trips into zone C to break even. For a tourist, this means most likely arriving and departing at Schönefeld *and* visiting Potsdam, since most other points of interest are in zones A and B.

Comment: So a weekly ticket to AB is preferable? Which zone Tegel airport is?

Comment: @py_script, that depends on where you want to go and how many museums you plan to see. Tegel is B, so that would be a cheap way for the *transport* requirements if you stay in the AB zone.

Comment: Yeah, I am not if anything interesting is in zone C. Regarding museums I am plannign to go Pergamon, Jewish, museum of technology and Wall memorial for sure.